# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se repitan mis elementos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un inventario con items que se han comprado, y pues ya se muestran con el problema de que cuando se ha comprado un insumo varias veces, este se repite, me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera en la que pueda simplemente sumar su "cantidad" y evitar que se repita el mismo nombre? A su vez lo mismo necesitaría para "total" y el nombre que apareciera solo una vez.

Adjunto captura de lo que me muestra y de los datos que recibo del servidor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aprecio mucho si alguien puede ayudarme con eso :)

Adjunto el codigo de lo mostrado en la imagen:

```
$.get('../api/v1/locales/' + id_local + '/insumos', {}, function(returnedData) {
            if (returnedData["error"] == false) {
                returnedData["compras"].forEach(function(compras){
                    compras["compra_insumos"].forEach(function(cI){
                        cantidad = cI["cantidad"];
                        nombre = cI["proveedor_insumo"]["insumo"]["nombre"];
                        total = cI["total"];

                        $("#Insumo-data").append("<tr><td>" + nombre + "</td><td>" + cantidad + "</td><td>$" + total + "</td></tr>");
                    });
                });
            } else
                SweetAlert("error", "Existió un error. Por favor actualice la ventana.");
        })
```

Comment: De donde provienen los datos?

Comment: Ahi en la captura estan: todo sale desde "compras" y "compra_insumos" solo que en algunas ocasiones hay compras repetidas, alli es que me gustaria que simplemente se muestre uno con el valor total de los duplicados

Comment: Me refiero a si vienen de una base de datos.

Comment: Si, vienen de una base de datos mysql

Comment: Entonces deberias agrupar los datos en mysql por el campo insumo y sumar cantidad y costo.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT insumo, SUM(cantidad), SUM(costo) FROM tabla GROUP BY (insumo);
```

Con esa consulta se debería de agrupar por insumo y sumar la cantidad de los costos y la cantidad.

También están las funciones COUNT() y AVG() que te podrían interesar un poco.

Comment: Tambien deberias acumular la cantidad con sum(cantidad)

Comment: Tienes razón, no había visto que se me pasó ese detalle